# Flutter custom widget test with callback function fails

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I've implemented a custom widget for which I'm trying to create test cases. Below is my custom widget. It has one method which is onObserve. So whenever controller detects some data, it calls onObserve method.

```
class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<Model>? onObserve;

  const CustomWidget({super.key, required this.onObserve});

  @override
  State<CustomWidget> createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}
class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyController mController = MyController();

    return Stack(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 350,
            height: 350,
            child: MyObserver(
                controller: mController,
                onDetect: (code, args) {
                  if (code.value != null) {
                      //...TODO
                      widget.onObserve!(myObservedData);
                  }
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my test case :

```
testWidgets('on observe', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    var mModel = Model();

    await tester.pumpWidget(MyWrapper(Scaffold(body: CustomWidget(
      onObserve: (value) {
        value.address = '5, ABC-123';
        mModel = value;
      },
    ))));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byType(CustomWidget), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.byType(MyObserver), findsOneWidget);
    expect(mModel.address, '5, ABC-123');
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });
```

This test case is failing always because it's not going into onObserve method. What I'm trying to do is setting data in onObserve method and verifying with `expect(mModel.address, '5, ABC-123');` which is always failing. Is there anything wrong with above test ?

Comment: can you show MyObserver class code ?

Comment: Is there any reason for creating the controller in the build method?

Comment: @manhtuan21 - MyObserver is nothing but just a part of library. It's not MyObserver actually, it's renamed to MyObserver from something else.

Comment: @Josteve - Controller is something from library that I'm using.  Is there any solution for above test code.. ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `onDetect` of your `MyObserve` will only be triggered if something happen

```
await tester.pumpWidget(MyWrapper(Scaffold(body: CustomWidget(
      onObserve: (value) {
        value.address = '5, ABC-123';
        mModel = value;
      },
    ))));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```

Above section of your code only `await` for your `CustomWidget` build done, it doesn't wait for onDetect to be triggered, so code inside `onObserve` will not be called
I don't know excalty your MyObserve do, so I fake this example, you can follow it:

```
testWidgets('on observe', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    var mModel;
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyWrapper(
      home: Scaffold(body: CustomWidget(
        onObserve: (value) {
          mModel = value;
        },
      )),
    ));

    // You maybe need to implement code to trigger your MyObserve class here
    final CustomWidgetState customWidgetState = tester.state(find.byType(CustomWidget));
    customWidgetState.triggerOnDetect();

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byType(CustomWidget), findsOneWidget);
    expect(mModel, 123);
  });
```

Comment: MyObserver is class from a library that scans text. Once text is detected, I get it in 'code' from onDetect(code, args) and then I trigger onObserve function of customized class and pass data to onObserve method.